# ductless air handler install

Tags: hvac, heat-pump, mini-split, ductless

So I am about to embark on an install of a 6 zone ductless system and I have 2 questions around installing the air handlers in each bedroom.  I am using a branch distribution box which needs to be located indoors.  I plan to run my line sets to 3 bedrooms on the second floor through an a vacated vent  up to the second floor and onward.

First Question: At the air handler install point I was assuming I can run the line sets along the ceiling, but the manuals for the air handlers do not show an upward piping orientation. It only shows left, right and downward.  I assume I can persuade it to slope upwards about a foot to meet the BD line sets from the ceiling run.  Is that correct?

Second Question: I realize the condensate always needs to be downward pitched, but could I also run that along the ceiling - tie all three together and down the chute to a condensate pump in the basement? Not looking to cut along a wall to run pitched condensate piping.

My house is a city row house that is over 120 years old and the space between the second floor ceiling and the flat roof is less that crawling height.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have installed quite a few ductless systems in the last few years. All of the systems have had horizontal then downward sloping line sets. I would check with the MFG as going up may trap oil in the evaporators. The drains must be lower or a pump will be needed even a 1/2” rise will cause the water to drain at the unit inside the house if there is not a built in safety that shuts it down (I am not a fan of condensate pumps I have seen two many failures).

Comment: Thanks Ed! I rather rely on gravity as well.